# Azure - RoleEnvironement events not firing when role is rebooted or taken down for patching

Tags: azure

In short, is there a RoleEnvironment event that I can handle in code when any other role in my deployment is rebooted or taken offline for patching?

I've got an application in production that has both web roles for an web front end and web roles running WCF services as an application layer (business logic, data access etc). The web layer communicates with the WCF layer over an internal endpoint as we don't want to expose the services at this point in time. So this means it is not possible to use the load balancer to call my service layer through a single url.

So I have to load balance requests to the WCF web roles manually. This has caused problems in the past when a machine has been recycled by the fabric controller for patching.

I'm handling the RoleEnvironment.Changing and RoleEnvironment.Changed events to adjust the list of backend web roles I am communicating with, which works well in testing when I make a configuration change to increase or decrease the number of instances in my deployment. But if I reboot a role through the portal, this does not fire the RoleEnvironment events.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RoleEnvironment.Changing will be fired ["before a change to the *service configuration*"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.changing.aspx) (my emphasis).  In this case no *configuration* change is occurring, your service is still *configured* to have exactly the same number of instances.  AFAIK there is no way to know when your deployment is taken offline, and clearly their are instances where notice *cannot* be given in advance (e.g. hardware failure).  Therefore you have to code for communication failure, intercept the error, and try another role instance.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, that makes sense and fits with my experiences so far. It's a shame as handling the communication failure is a lot more difficult :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can intercept RoleEnvironment changes from a different Role easily.

I would suggest that you have RoleEnvironment changes trapped in the Role where they occur, handle them by throwing a message/record onto some persisted storage and let your Web-roles check that storage either on a regular schedule or every-time when you communicate to the WCF-roles.

Basically, if you're doing your own internal load-balancing, you need a mechanism for registration/tear-down of your instances so that you can manage your wcf workers

Comment: Thanks Igorek, I was confused as to what triggered the event. As Oliver Bock points out, it is only a configuration change that we are notified of, but I think all roles receive notification of the configuration change whether or not they are affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure storage queues to post a message when a role is going down and have a worker role that listens on that queue and adjusts things accordingly.